# Checking if an array is unimodal

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, python-3.x, comparative-review

[Codeforces problem 831A](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/831/A) says:

> Array of integers is *unimodal*, if:
>
> - it is strictly increasing in the beginning;
> - after that it is constant;
> - after that it is strictly decreasing.
>
> The first block (increasing) and the last block (decreasing) may be absent. It is allowed that both of this blocks are absent.
>
> For example, the following three arrays are unimodal: [5, 7, 11, 11, 2, 1], [4, 4, 2], [7], but the following three are not unimodal: [5, 5, 6, 6, 1], [1, 2, 1, 2], [4, 5, 5, 6].
>
> Write a program that checks if an array is unimodal.

I solved this using two methods in python3.5.
I was expecting method 2 to be faster than method 1 but auto-grader showed the opposite.
So, I wanted to know the reason that what makes the difference here?

#### Method 1

```
a, lst = int(input()), input().split()

lst = [int(ch) for ch in lst]

def f(m, n, flag):
    if flag == 1:
        return m < n
    elif flag == 2:
        return m == n
    else:
        return m > n


def is_modal(a, lst):
    flag = 1
    for i in range(1, a):
        if f(lst[i - 1], lst[i], flag):
            continue
        else:
            if flag == 3:
                return "NO"
            flag += 1
            if f(lst[i - 1], lst[i], flag):
                continue
            else:
                if flag == 3:
                    return "NO"
                flag += 1
                if f(lst[i - 1], lst[i], flag):
                    continue
                else:
                    return "NO"
    return "YES"

print(is_modal(a, lst))
```

It seems to be overly complicated to me, at first I solved it in this way but I did not like it so I tried another way, hence came at method 2.

#### Method 2

```
a, lst = int(input()), input().split()
lst = [int(ch) for ch in lst]


def is_modal(a, lst):
    i = 1
    for i in range(i, a):
        if not (lst[i - 1] < lst[i]):
            break
    else:
        return "YES"

    for i in range(i, a):
        if not (lst[i - 1] == lst[i]):
            break
    else:
        return "YES"

    for i in range(i, a):
        if not (lst[i - 1] > lst[i]):
            return "NO"
    else:
        return "YES"

print(is_modal(a, lst))
```

It looks cleaner and simpler but still, it came out to be slower one.

And apart from comparing these codes, any other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 5):

The following code is similar to your method 2:

```
def is_unimodal(seq):
    i = 1
    end = len(seq)
    while i < end and seq[i - 1] < seq[i]:
        i += 1
    while i < end and seq[i - 1] == seq[i]:
        i += 1
    while i < end and seq[i - 1] > seq[i]:
        i += 1
    return i == end
```

This code probably looks more like C than Python, but I expect it to be fast and readable.

Comment: @GarethRees It looks much better than method 2, why is it slower?